# How can I set a div height to match that of a child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I've create a div container width some child div's in it. The child displays pictures via `img` tags with percentage widths.

When I inspect the height of the parent div, my browser says it is `0px`, even though the pictures inside the child div have a non-zero height.

How can I set the parent div automatically to the height of the greatest child when I only work width percent? This must work too, when I tweak the image sizes in the browser manually.

I tried to set the height and width of the parent div with jQuery, but it works only once and not dynamically. When I reload the page, the function will set the height of 16px.

Comment: if you set the chlld's css clear property the parent div will extend to the bottom of the child.

Comment: It might be helpful if you pasted the code in so that people can get a better understanding of what you are asking. That is if your question isn't answered already.

Comment: I have edited your post for grammar and spelling, hopefully without losing any of your meaning. @DarceyMckelvey is right; if you add the code and can point to exactly what it is that is incorrect, it can help answers to give you a specific fix. Also, I'm not sure from your question whether there is any visible defect you are trying to correct or if you're just asking about the finer points of css inheritance and browser rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but is this what you're looking for?

HTML:

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.out {
    background-color: blue;
}
.in {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xm2gwdjd/

Comment: yes, but it not work width floated childs.
.in { ... float: left; }

I think, I must work width overflow: auto in .out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this css with Parent div

```
overfolw:auto;
```

For Parent div

```
dispaly:table;
```

For child div :

`display:table-row;`

Comment: fyi, overflow and display are misspelt. :)